# Execute powershell script from Autoit?

Tags: powershell, autoit

How do I execute a powershell script from AutoIt code?

I assume it might be something like:

```
Runwait(@ComSpec & " /c powershell.exe c:\Mytest.ps1", "", @SW_HIDE)
```

or

```
Runwait(powershell.exe c:\Mytest.ps1", "", @SW_HIDE)
```

But neither of those seem to be working.

Comment: `powershell.exe -File C:\MyTest.ps1` (if script execution policy permits).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Runwait("powershell.exe c:\Mytest.ps1", "", @SW_HIDE)
```

and right click on au3 file and select 'run script(x64)'

test powershell script that i used:

```
"heelllo" >> h:\somesome.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, this basically works... when I right click and run as "run script(x64)" it works fine... but when I'm in the SciTE script editor, with the script open, and run the script by pressing "F5"... It doesnt work from there.  Any thoughts?  I tried running the script editor as administrator in windows but nothing.

Answer (score -1):

I the end, this solution seems to work:

```
Local $iPID = Run('powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -windowstyle hidden -noninteractive -nologo -file C:\MyScript.ps1"', "c:\", @SW_HIDE, $STDOUT_CHILD)
; Wait until the process has closed using the PID returned by Run.
ProcessWaitClose($iPID)
; Read the Stdout stream of the PID returned by Run. 
Local $sOutput = StdoutRead($iPID)
```